# auto vectorization with modulo index?

Tags: c++, clang, vectorization, auto-vectorization

I'm trying to make clang++ auto-vectorize a simple bit scrambling loop that does something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < sz; ++i) {
   dst[i] = src[i] ^ key[i]
}
```

if `dst`, `src` and `key` are the same length, the compiler has no problem vectorizing this loop, but what I really want to do is this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < sz; ++i) {
   dst[i] = src[i] ^ key[i % 64];
}
```

I don't need key to be as long as the data, but when I add the `% 64` the vectorizer runs away and I'm left with a normal loop. This happens even with `% 8` which is the size of the SIMD registers. The next thing I tried was this:

```
char d = 0x80
for(int i = 0; i < sz; ++i) {
   dst[i] = src[i] ^ d;
   ++d;
}
```

but the vectorizer didn't like this as well.
Doing this however:

```
for(int i = 0; i < sz; ++i) {
   dst[i] = src[i] ^ 0x80;
   ++d;
}
```

did get vectorized fine, but having a key of just one byte is shorter than what I hoped for.

Is there a way to do something like this in a way that pleases the vectorizer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can reproduce this with Apple's (Xcode) clang. Using modulo-64 blocks appears to satisfy the vectorizer:

```
int i = 0; /* current index. */

int szd = sz / 64;
int szm = sz % 64;
for (int j = 0; j < szd; j++)
{
    for (int k = 0; k < 64; i++, k++)
        dst[i] = src[i] ^ key[k];
}

for (int k = 0; k < szm; i++, k++)
     dst[i] = src[i] ^ key[k];
```

Comment: @harold - yes. And depending on the `dst` / `src` elements, it even yields inner loops with multiple `xorps`.

Comment: Brilliant! I made a slight edit that produces performance equal to libc memcpy :)